# angular full calendar event dosen't display

Tags: javascript, css, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I use angular full calender v4 for display events in calendar but I have error when I want to display events in timeGridDay and timeGridWeek i have error of display , is displayed or hours.
example of errors display events of week:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxSCS.png)

and also example of errors display events in day:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJts2.png)

code html:

```
            <div class="col-lg-12">
        <full-calendar
            #myCalendar
            defaultView="dayGridMonth"
            [slotLabelFormat]="slotLabelFormat"
            [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
            [header]="{
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
            }"
            dir="rtl"
            [events]="listEvents"
            [eventTimeFormat]="eventTimeFormat"
            (eventClick)="handleEventClick($event)"
        >
        </full-calendar>
    </div>
```

code ts:

```
            eventTimeFormat = { hour12: false, hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' };
        slotLabelFormat = [ { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: false } ]
```

Comment: It looks like you either forgot to load one or more of the CSS files required by fullCalendar, and/or you have customised the CSS in your page in a way that conflicts with fullCalendar's CSS.

Comment: how to load all full calendar css files??

Comment: The same way you load any CSS files. It's unclear what the problem is exactly. How do you load CSS files into your page right now?